# Checking if user doesn't allow Canvas App in Facebook C# MVC

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to track the number of users who did not allow my app during authorisation using the Facebook C# SDK and ASP.NET MVC.

By specifying the CanvasAuthorize attribute on my landing page, user will get redirected to 
a url like this:

```
canvasurl/facebookredirect.axd?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.&state=eyJyIjoiaHR0cDovL2FwcHMuZmFjZWJvb2suY29tL25pdmVhdGVzdGVydCJ9
```

My question here is..how do i code my app in such a way that i can read the querystrings and track the number of times my app has been denied access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the CanvasAuthorize attrib on your action there is also a parameter for CancelUrlPath, like so:

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions="user_likes,email", CancelUrlPath="YOUR_PATH_HERE")]
```

This will allow you to set the path to an action that you can do all the tracking you like.

Hope this answers your question.

-Joey

Comment: thanks! sorry i don't have enuff reputation to accept your answer as useful!